# Core-plot usage in the project

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using core-plot in my project , the project was done in some other systems where it was working well. when i try to build the same project in my system , i get many errors one among them which is predominant is

coreplot-cocoatouch.h no such file or directory.

how to debug this error ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be that the project from where u imported it have used the cross reference to the coreplot project,and when you have transfered it to you system you might not have the coreplot project existing in your system. This might be one of the problem because coreplot library is generally added as a cross reference and it is not preferable to copy complete core-plot project in the working project to access its library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy core-plot source to your system. And reference CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj in your application. You have to change your project settings to make core-plot to work. You can refer these links. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications 
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application